# Anaconda再インストール後に過去の仮想環境がスタートメニューに残ってしまう

Tags: windows, anaconda, anaconda3

Win10、64bitの環境です。

表題の通り、Anacondaを一度アンインストールしたあとに再インストールすると、スタートメニューの中にJupyter notebook(仮想環境名)のような項目が残ってしまいます。
Anaconda Navigatorでみると過去の仮想環境は消えているのですが…

どのように対処すればよろしいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

スタートメニューの実体はショートカットなので、やや強引な方法になりますがエクスプローラーで下記のフォルダを開いて直接削除する方法があります。
(一部のフォルダは隠しファイル扱いになっているので、順に辿ろうとすると設定変更が必要かもしれません。)

```
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\スタートメニュー\
```

少し慎重になるなら、該当のショートカットを右クリックでプロパティを開き、「ファイルの場所を開く」で(アンインストール済みなら)ファイルが見つからないことを確認してから削除してもよいでしょう。