# Anaconda3を完全にアンインストールしたい。

Tags: anaconda3, jupyter-lab

Anaconda3をアンインストールしたく、
Anacondaの公式ドキュメントを参照しました。
が、完全にアンインストール出来ません。
Anaconda3を完全にアンインストールするご教授お願いします。

▲Anacondaの公式ドキュメントを参照したアンインストールの手順

１， (base) C:\Users\genki>conda install anaconda-clean
２， (base) C:\Users\genki>anaconda-clean
３， (base) C:\Users\genki>anaconda-clean --yes

▲Anacondaの公式ドキュメントURL
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

Comment: それぞれ、`Windows10の再セットアップで設定を変えることができました。`, `Anaconda3のヴァージョンアップをすると、元のブラウザ(Edge)になりました。`, `ジュピターラボの起動時、ブラウザ設定は聞いてこなく、Edgeの起動となります。` というのが厳密には`何を対象`として`どうなるはず`のものが`そうならずにこうなっている`等の詳細が曖昧です。そしてそれらの何が問題/疑問なのでしょう？ その辺を追記すると相応しい助言や回答が得られ易いでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。精読して、熟考して編集します。

Comment: コメントを編集してみました。

Answer (score 0):

コメントに書いたことはやってもらった方が良いとして。
タイトルの「Anaconda3を完全にアンインストールしたい。」については、以下のように考えられるでしょう。

まず参照先と同じ情報の日本語版とその他
[Anaconda3をしっかりアンインストールするにはどうしたら良いですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/63312/26370)
■質問追記対応：
上記記事の最後の以下の作業が行われていないようです。追加で作業してください。

> - その後コントロールパネルから Anaconda をアンインストールする。

[Anaconda再インストール後に過去の仮想環境がスタートメニューに残ってしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62207/26370)

---

そして残った設定情報のディレクトリ等を削除すれば良いでしょう。

- エクスプローラーの表示メニューで「ファイル名拡張子」「隠しファイル」を表示するチェックを付ける
- エクスプローラーの表示メニューのオプションの「表示」タブで「保護されたオペレーティングシステムファイルを表示しない(推奨)」のチェックを外す
- 適用した後に「フォルダーの表示」の「フォルダーに適用」をクリックして適用

だいたい以下のディレクトリでanaconda,conda,jupyter,ipython,pipといったanaconda,jupyterやpythonに関連している名前の付いたフォルダを削除していけば良いでしょう。
一応サブディレクトリやファイル名/ファイル内容などは確認して関連しそうかどうかは個々に判断してください。

```
C:\Users\ユーザー名
C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Local
C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Roaming
C:\ProgramData
```

例えばこんなディレクトリが考えられます。
ただし必ず{有る/関連する}とは限りません。削除の判断は自己責任で行ってください。

```
.cache
.conda
.continuum
.ipynb_checkpoints
.ipython
.jupyter
.keras
.matplotlib
.spyder-py3
anaconda3
library_dir
ContinuumIO
pip
.anaconda
jupyter
```