# JupyterLabでcondaコマンドを使えなくなってしまった

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab, conda

## 本題

JupyterLabでcondaコマンドを使えるようにするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

## 経緯

JupyterLabで仮想環境の削除をしようとしたときに，先に

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall environment_name
```

を実行してから

```
conda remove -n 環境名 --all
```

を実行しました．そのあと，この「仮想環境の削除」が原因でないかもしれませんが，`conda install`などのcondaコマンドを使用できなくなりました．この操作をする以前は問題なく使えていました．

`conda install` コマンドを実行したときに出力されるエラーメッセージ:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

conda-script.pyの中身：

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
# Before any more imports, leave cwd out of sys.path for internal 'conda shell.*' commands.
# see https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6549
if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1].startswith('shell.') and sys.path and sys.path[0] == '':
    # The standard first entry in sys.path is an empty string,
    # and os.path.abspath('') expands to os.getcwd().
    del sys.path[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from conda.cli import main
    sys.exit(main())
```

## 試したこと

Anaconda Navigatorをアンインストールしてから再インストールをしました．しかし改善されず．

Comment: まず「JupyterLabでcondaコマンドを使える」というのがどういう状況や手順を想定しているのかを追記した方が良いと思われます。検索して見つかるのがこんな記事ですが、それらの何かに相当しますか？ [図解！Jupyter Labを徹底解説！(インストール・使い方・拡張機能)](https://ai-inter1.com/jupyter-lab/), [Anaconda + JupyterLab 仮想環境備忘録](https://note.com/aimarsa/n/n6cea4089ca67), [Anaconda仮想環境のカーネルをJupyterLabで使用する方法](https://sakizo-blog.com/13/), [JupyterLabでcondaの環境切替](https://qiita.com/val_geass/items/3872f9b4c6fe3bea5dfa), [Anaconda環境にJupyterlabをインストールして使う](https://ryjkmr.com/anaconda-jupyterlab-install/) ちなみにアンインストールはこちらを参考にすると良いかも。[Anaconda3を完全にアンインストールしたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/82381/26370)

Comment: condaコマンドはすべて (例えば`conda activate 環境` も)利用できない状況ですか？
PATHも通ってるはずなのに全て使えないなら完全にアンインストールして再インストールしたほうがよいでしょう。(その前に)何が起きたのか知りたいなら(少なくとも)`conda-meta/history`ファイルは保持しておいて内容確認するとよいかも

Comment: @kunif 意図したとおりの返事ができているか不安ですが，たとえば`conda install torch`でtorchをインストールしたい場合に上記のエラーが出るというありさまです．

Comment: @oriri 完全アンインストールは以前試していて，そこで.ipythonの削除ができないという旨のエラーが起きてそれから手を付けていなかったのですが，自分で.ipythonフォルダを削除して完全アンインストールをしてから再インストールをしたら直りました！