# Anaconda Navigatorが起動しません

Tags: python, anaconda

Anaconda Navigatorが起動しません。

今まで正常に動いていたものが、ある日突然、Anaconda Navigatorが起動しなくなりましたので、対処方法を教えてください。

Windows ボタン >Anaconda3 (64bit) > Anaconda > Anaconda Navigator をクリックしても、Anaconda Navigator が起動できません。（一瞬黒色ウインドウが表示されるもののすぐに消えてしまいます。）

当方環境:Windows10 Pro 64bit

再インストール
Windowsボタン > 設定 > アプリと機能 から、Anaconda3を一度アンインストールして、再度インストールするも、症状改善されません。
※インストーラー：Anaconda3-2023.03-1-Windows-x86_64

現在の状況

1. Windows ボタン >Anaconda3 (64bit) > Anaconda > Anaconda Navigator をクリックしても、Anaconda Navigator が起動できません。（一瞬黒色ウインドウが表示されるもののすぐに消えてしまいます。）
2. Anaconda Powershell Prompt
   Windowsボタン >Anaconda3 (64bit) > Anaconda Powershell Prompt
   を開くと下記のメッセージが出る。

※[ユーザ名]は、半角英字 半角スペース 半角英字 からなるユーザ名です。

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" shell.powershell activate "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3"'
Invoke-Expression : 引数が空の文字列であるため、パラメーター 'Command' にバインドできません。
発生場所 C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:76 文字:36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression]、ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keExpressionCommand
PS C:\Users\[ユーザ名]>
```

3. Anaconda Prompt
   Windowsボタン >Anaconda3 (64bit) > Anaconda Prompt
   を開くと下記のメッセージが出る。

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" shell.cmd.exe activate "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3" '

C:\Users\[ユーザ名]>
```

4. 環境変数Path
   システムのプロパティ > 環境変数 > 変数:Path
   には、一番上の行から下記の環境変数名が入っている。当該フォルダが存在することも確認済み

```
C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3
C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Scripts
（以下ほかの環境変数名）
```

Comment: 「今まで正常に動いていたものが、ある日突然、Anaconda Navigatorが起動しなくなりました」とありますが、何らかの変化点があったのでは？と思うのですがいかがでしょうか？（直近でアップデートされたとかpipとcondaを同一仮想環境で使ってしまったとかはないでしょうか？）

Comment: Anacondaのアンインストールはこちらの記事の情報を参考に。[Anaconda3を完全にアンインストールしたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/82381/26370) それから状況は違いますがこんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。[WindowsのAnacondaが動作しないときの対処方法とより良いPython環境について](https://codeaid.jp/win-anaconda/), [Anaconda Navigatorが起動しなくなり、Anaconda上のPythonが動かなくなったときの解決法](https://1978works.com/2021/11/03/how-to-solve-when-anaconda-navigator-does-not-start-and-python-on-anaconda-does-not-work/)

Comment: merinoさま　ありがとうございます。思い当たる原因が複数あり、わかりません。Anaconda Navigatorで環境をアップデートしたり、Visual Basic CodeでRustを使い始めたり、していますので、どれが原因か分からず困っているという状況です。OSを再インストールせず、現在のユーザ名のままでAnaconda Navigatorを再度使えるようにする方法はありませんでしょうか？

Comment: `conda`コマンドは利用可能ですか？ `conda info`, `conda activate base`,  `conda list` など。動くのなら `conda update anaconda` で直ることもあるようです

Comment: @ oriri さま　Anaconda Powershell Prompt　および　Anaconda Prompt　で試しましたが、できませんでした。

Comment: @kunif  様　ありがとうございます。お示しいただいた方法を試しましたが、改善しませんでした。Anaconda3を完全にアンインストールしたい、WindowsのAnacondaが動作しないときの対処方法とより良いPython環境について　を試しましたが、改善しませんでした。　 Anaconda Navigatorが起動しなくなり、Anaconda上のPythonが動かなくなったときの解決法 –　は、①Anaconda Navigatorのアップデート、②Anaconda全体のアップデートは、Anaconda Promptが動かないのでできません。③Numpyにエラー。Windowsの環境変数に「C:\Users\ユーザー名\Anaconda3\Library\bin」というパスを追加、④Windowsマシンを再起動　を試しましたが、改善しませんでした。

Comment: そうすると問題は最初のエラーメッセージから推測して、PowerShellの仕様が変わった(あるいは組み込まれているv5.1ではなく.NET Core系(最新はv7.3.4)のPowerShellを追加したかその逆に版数を下げた)か、PowerShellの何かの設定を変えたか、環境変数PATHの中での記述順番を変えた、等の可能性があるのかもしれません。

Comment: @kunif 　様　ありがとうございます。ご懸念の可能性について、どのように対処したらよろしいか、詳しく教えていただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: エラーメッセージからの推測なので、何をどう調べるのが良いか具体的な手順は直ぐには出てきませんね。最後に正常に起動できていた時点から、起動できなくなった時点までの間に、PCに何か変更を行ったかを思い出してみて、それらを元に戻してみるか、どうしても分からなければOSのクリーンインストールから始めてみるのが良いかもしれません。

Comment: > で試しましたが、できませんでした。
… 何を試そうとしてどんなメッセージが出たか 分からないので (仮に何か対処可能だったとしても)どうしようもない。もう少し具体的に書いたほうがよいでしょう

Comment: @oriri 様  Anaconda Powershell Promptの場合

(1) まずAnaconda Powershell Promptを起動すると、質問文に記述したエラーが出ます。

(2) conda infoを入力すると、
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" info'
というエラーが出ます。

Comment: @oriri様  (3)conda activate baseを入力すると、
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" shell.powershell activate base'
Invoke-Expression : 引数が空の文字列であるため、パラメーター 'Command' にバインドできません。（つづく）

Comment: @oriri様 （つづき）発生場所 C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:76 文字:36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression]、ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keExpressionCommand
というエラーがでます。

Comment: @oriri様 (4) conda listを入力すると、
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" list'
というエラーが出ます。

(5)conda update anacondaを入力すると、
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" update anaconda'
というエラーが出ます。

Comment: @oriri様  Anaconda Promptの場合

(1) まずAnaconda Promptを起動すると、質問文に記述したエラーが出ます。

(2) conda infoを入力すると、
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" info'
というエラーが出ます。

(3)conda activate baseを入力すると、
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" shell.cmd.exe activate base '
というエラーがでます。

Comment: @oriri様  
(4) conda listを入力すると、
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" list'
というエラーが出ます。

(5)conda update anacondaを入力すると、
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\[ユーザ名]\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" update anaconda'
というエラーが出ます。